# wp8 c# azure client side authentication mobile services issue

Tags: c#, authentication, azure, windows-phone-8.1, azure-mobile-services

I am just starting out with a windows azure mobile services .net backend, and am running into so many headaches as a new programmer. I have gone into my azure mobile services account and downloaded the todoitems demo app (c# for .net backend). I then followed the tutorials regarding adding facebook authentication, but I am absolutely not pleased by this method, as it shuts down the app for a few seconds. As such, I set out determined to create a custom authentication login page which ties to my mobile backend.

I found [this article](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-get-started-custom-authentication/) and thought, "Great!" only to realize that I had no clue how to catch a user created account from a textbox and to pass it along to the public class RegistrationRequest. The example at the end of the link shows how to connect to a local machine - but I want it to connect to my actual database at the following location:  https://mycustomapp.azure-mobile.net, return a token, and continueon.

What is frustrating is that I am able to obtain a facebook authentication token, as well as user information. BUT, I have no idea how to generate a windows azure mobile auth token so that the client may write/retrieve data from my azure table.

Essentially my question is this - using the above link, how in the world may I take a user's username and password from a textbox, run it through the RegistrationRequest, and not have to pop advil on this? Do I need to pass my facebook token? I assume not?

I am also not using a facebook SDK or anything like that - simply put, I am using the above site's code trying to get an auth token from my azure mobile services, despite having one from facebook already, to authenticate a user against my azure mobile services data table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a FB token, the easiest way to login to your mobile service is by using the FB token, then you don't need to make a custom UI/etc.

This can be done by calling

```
var token = new JObject();
token.Add("access_token", "access_token_value");
await client.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook, token);
```

see: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library/#authentication, Client Flow for more

Comment: Hi phillipv, this is the code I was definitely looking for. I eventually found this code as well in one of the Azure's many code documents, and it provides everything I need - seamless authentication and flow. I just wish it was more prominently displayed, due to the alternative of waiting around on a blank screen. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to login to your service with a Facebook account, you do not need to implement a custom authentication and to capture user name and password in your own textbox controls.

You should be able to use MobileServiceClient.LoginAsync() and pass as parameters the provider that you want to use. Check this [article](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-windows-phone-get-started-users/%20article) fro more information.

Comment: Hi Jogy, thank you for the response. The linked article is 404ed, but I can guess it is similar to what phillipv provided. I appreciated the added clarification as well, and thus the upvote.